# Math Cal­li­graphic let­ters in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, math-mode, calligraphy

How can I produce exactly the same letter as in the attached picture ? I work with the TexMaker.

[image: Letter]

thanks,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)

Comment: @texenthusiast I am not sure, what exactly do you want to add, but I can see that you have rights to edition, so please make corrections for future users.

Comment: This _is_ a clear duplicate, since you can find it on [Detexify](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm7ZM.png).

Comment: @texenthusiast Now I understand. Well done! I know such a type of calligraphic letters from rather old mathematical books.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calrsfs}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{E}$
\end{document}
```

[image]